# Remove all div with same html value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following html structure

```
 <div class="messagesdate">03 Aug, 2021</div>
  <div class="messagesdate">03 Aug, 2021</div>
  <div class="messagesdate">03 Aug, 2021</div>
  <div class="messagesdate">04 Aug, 2021</div>
  <div class="messagesdate">04 Aug, 2021</div>
```

How can I do a global function that will run through all the div and remove all with same date except for the first one?

this is what I did so far and I got stuck

```
var found = {};
        $('.messagesdate').each(function (i) {
            var $this = $(this);
            if (found[$this.html()]) {
                $this.remove();
            } else {
                found[$this.html()] = true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do you want to remove duplicate div with the same date?

Comment: Yes except for the first div

Comment: What is the expected output for your example then?

Comment: I think the easiest would be to 1) build a list of unique values 2) delete all existing tags 3) recreate tags based on unique values found in point 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done [without jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

```js
const dates = {};
document.querySelectorAll("div.messagesdate")
  .forEach(div =>
    dates[div.textContent] ? div.remove() : dates[div.textContent] = 1);
```

```html
<div class="messagesdate">03 Aug, 2021</div>
<div class="messagesdate">03 Aug, 2021</div>
<div class="messagesdate">03 Aug, 2021</div>
<div class="messagesdate">04 Aug, 2021</div>
<div class="messagesdate">04 Aug, 2021</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.messagesdate').each(function (i) {

         if(i == 0)
           var firstElement = $(this);
         else{
              if($(this).html() == firstElement.html()){
              $(this).remove()
           }
     }    

});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 